# Make image not shift siblings to side

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where if I add an image as a sibling to an element then that element will shift over to accommodate the inserted image. What I want is the element to stay horizontally centered even if the image is inserted. Here is a picture of the issue:

[image: pic]

Each row is its own div with a `p` element and an optional image, which is the red explanation point. I want the `p` element with text "Corrupted" to stay horizontally aligned even with the inserted sibling.

Here is my CSS:

```
#friendsList div{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    display: table
    width: 100%;
}

#friendsList div p{
    display: inline;
}
```

The inserted image has css like this:

```
#friendsList div img {
   margin-bottom: 5px, 
   float: right, 
   vertical-align:middle
}
```

Is there a way to have the `p` element stay horizontally aligned even when it has a sibling?

EDIT*** Here is a CSSdeck example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/2uel0ogm

Comment: add HTML code so we can help you

Comment: Ok I'll try, one sec

Comment: image is in `<p>` or is sibling of `<p>`?

Comment: I added an example, thanks for the patience!! http://cssdeck.com/labs/2uel0ogm The image I'm using is missing but it still shows the effect.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal sibling, check out my example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place image **left** to the `p` tag and give `float: right` to the `img`.
see the example

```css
#friendsList div{
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
     margin: 0;
 display: table
 width: 100%;
 background: orange;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

#friendsList div p{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

#friendsList div img {
 float: right;
 height: 25px;
 width: 25px;
 margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="friendsList">
  <div><p>first</p></div>
  <div><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/128/Emotes-face-smile-icon.png" alt=""><p>second</p></div>
</div>
```

**Alternative solution**(using `position` property)

```css
#friendsList div{
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin: 0;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 background: orange;
 border: 1px solid red;
 position: relative;
}

#friendsList div p{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

#friendsList div img {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="friendsList">
 <div><p>first</p></div>
 <div><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/128/Emotes-face-smile-icon.png" alt=""><p>second</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, this answer rules! Thanks :)

Comment: @MarksCode haha there are such people ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following possibilities come to my mind:

1. Add the image as background image and use [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).
2. Apply `position: relative` to the div and something like `position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px;` to the image. This makes the image absolutely positioned within the div as container.